# Xamarin PCL FFImageLoading: How to get the image without using CachedImage View

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library, image-loading, ffimageloading

Can we get the bitmap directly from FFImageLoading? I know i can use CachedImage View but I am currently using NControl and NGraphics to do custom drawing with touch events

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage)
    .Into(nativeImageView);
```

OR

```
var drawable = await ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage)
    .AsBitmapDrawableAsync();

var image = ImageService.Instance.LoadUrl(urlToImage)
    .AsUIImageAsync();
```